# Changing shower arm

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

So I was trying to move my shower head and it has snapped off, so I need to change it. Is it possible to do this myself, and if so what do I need to buy? I have looked online at shower arms, and they mention a standard BSP fitting? Please see photos below as to what is on the wall when I unscrew the current shower arm. Is this standard BSP? Or can I get an adapter for it? It just looks like a pipe to me  I’d also ideally like the current holes to be hidden too. Also, is the white thing attached to the wall, or would this also be changed? Many thanks for any help, I really am lost!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a shower head installation with mounting screws like you have.  What did this look like originally?

Comment: I have just added another photo to show what it was like originally!

Comment: Try twisting that piece, looks like plastic, at the end of the arm counterclockwise with a needle nose pliers to see if you can remove it....

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: Get the new parts of the same type and follow the instructions. Before you purchase one measure how far the tube protrudes from the wall to the nearest mm. You might have to know this to get a new shower arm that works with this tube length.

Answer (score 10):

### I'm not sure you did break anything off.

What's bugging me about your top picture is the pipe looks *awfully* thin-wall... too thin-wall to hold a thread.  So I don't believe that is iron pipe.

What clinched it for me was seeing the video you linked, which plainly shows a COPPER pipe, with use of an O-ring to establish seal to the shower head.

So I recommend you pull that remaining plastic piece off. Then, get a kitchen scrub-sponge (such as 3M Scotchbrite), and working wet, clean/polish the metal parts of the pipe coming out of the wall.  I bet it cleans up to a nice copper color.   Now you'll know what you are looking at.  Copper pipe is not threaded.*

All that cleaning isn't just for discovery or show.  The pipe needs to be pretty clean for the O-ring seal to work.

* Except for a very thick-wall variant which is iron (BSP) pipe that happens to be made out of copper or brass, but that's rare.

Comment: I agree, the wall equipment does not appear to have broken; can't speak about the rest of the unit...

Answer (score 3):

Generally what you have with a showerhead installation looks like this:

[image: From: https://lda.lowes.com/is/image/Lowes/DP18-174556_NPC_HT_Install_A_RainShowerHead_SCI_1_1?scl=1]

So the pipe that you broke the threads off should be threaded into the shower elbow that is attached to the wall behind the tile.

Using a pipe wrench you should be able to unscrew the pipe nipple that is sticking out.  You probably want to remove the piece that appears to be plastic before doing this so you don't break it.

There is the possibility that the pipe will break off in the wall and there is probably not much you can do if it's corroded into place but generally it should unscrew if it's been properly installed.

Comment: If I can unscrew it, can I then buy the shower arms designed for a BSP? I don’t have any pliers of any type so I’m going to have to try and just twist it

Comment: I don't know what a "BSP" is.  Please clarify.  But PLEASE use the correct tools.  A pipe wrench is not that expensive and will save you a lot of time and trouble.  Using the wrong tool can easily cause additional damage and lead to expensive repairs.

Comment: Also if it did break off in the wall, would I have to take the tiles off to fix it? At the moment it’s a jet of water, but at least we can still use it

Comment: Almost certainly.

Comment: According to google BSP stands for British standard pipe? Which means nothing to me, but I assume it’s something to do with the end of the pipe

Comment: BSP is 'British Standard Pipe (thread).  It comes in several sizes - 1/4", 3/8", 1/2" are common. Used extensively in Europe as well as UK. Never seemed to reflect the actual dimensions of anything, to me!

Comment: https://www.fixthebog.uk/aqualisa-fixed-arm-chrome-235013/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxdSHBhCdARIsAG6zhlUTgfRvsyYFPC3Pf20tdHVxgwA2eVICrQQnfStnYk5d5cJ3mL08SjIaAl-7EALw_wcB

I’m fairly sure the above link is what we currently have, if that’s of any help?

Comment: https://youtu.be/TpqWMWwMvXY

This is like how mine came off, with the plastic stuff underneath and the screws in the wall. So I have to buy a replacement with this fitting?

Comment: @jwh20 what you have pictured is how this is generally plumbed in the USA. It is done differently in other countries. Emily may assume there is no problem inside the wall, unless she would make one by trying to use a wrench on that tube coming out of the wall. She could polish the end of the tube with non-abrasive scouring powder and a soft rag, then install the new arm according to directions.

Comment: Do not attempt to unscrew this tube! You would almost certainly deform the tube. It is possibly soldered inside the wall not a threaded connection. Even if it is threaded as in the US, there is no need to unscrew it at this point.

Comment: @EmilyButcher The other side of your shower wall in a different room might be more accessible than breaking tile if you want to get a look at the thing and maybe even getting in a supporting wrench.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a direct replacement for this sort of pipe fitting - it’s an Aqualisa easy fit shower arm. The only problem I have now is the old parts are ever so slightly too big, I assume because they’re old and more modern = more compact. I just need to remove the one piece of plastic around the copper pipe. From looking at the new fittings, it has teeth inside - I have asked a question on this, on a different thread to keep it tidy. Thank you so much for everyone’s help!!

If anyone is interested: [Remove plastic fitting with teeth from copper pipe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/229471/remove-plastic-fitting-with-teeth-from-copper-pipe?noredirect=1#comment437778_229471)